# How to run Vite + Vue project frontend in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

[image]I have installed Vite inside a theme folder of my wordpress website. Is there anyway I can run the default front end of vue in wordpress?

What customizations do I need to make inside the theme folder?

What addition or removal should I do?

I have came across some tutorials but most are outdated or irrelevant.

This is my enqueue script:

```
<?php

function enqueue_vue_assets() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'vue-app', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://wordpress2.v3dev.komodefi.com/wp-content/themes/example/dist/assets/index-ec461b82.js', array(), '1.0', true );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'vue-app', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://wordpress2.v3dev.komodefi.com/wp-content/themes/example/dist/assets/index-fc5f319f.css', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_assets' );

?>
```

This is my functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Vue Twenty Seventeen Child Theme Functions and Definitions.
 * Requires Twenty Seventeen and only works in WordPress 4.7 or later.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

 // includes for the callbacks.
include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/enqueue-scripts.php' );

/* hooks and filters */

?>
```

The following is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#vue-app')
```

Comment: See tutorial how to get this to work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573766/how-to-properly-create-wp-enqueue-and-functions-script-to-run-vite-frontend/

Answer (score 0):

So I've only ever run react in a wordpress site as either a part of ReactPress Wordpress plugin on a single slug, or as a sort of headless install. Although, what I had was a wordpress install on a subdomain with a redirect on all pages to the domain, only exposing the login so that I could access the admin dashboard. My react frontend ran on the domain, where I'm simply leveraging the wordpress api to get the data.

Anywho, with that background out of the way, you could try something similar but with Vue...or you could also try the following:

### Integrate Vue assets into your Wordpress theme with the `wp_enque_scripts` action

1. Build your Vue project
2. Enque your Vue assetinto the Wordpress theme by enquing them - assuming project name of `my-vue-project`

```
function enqueue_vue_assets() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'vue-app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-vue-project/dist/js/app.js', array(), '1.0', true );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'vue-app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-vue-project/dist/css/app.css', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_assets' );
```

3. Add a container element to the `index.php` file of your Wordpress theme:

```
<div id="vue-app"></div>
```

4. Mount the app in your Vue project entry file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#vue-app')
```

I haven't tried this, but theoretically, it could work. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mate . My theme does not have index.php though IDK why it has got html files it is twentytwentythree theme of wordpress I have update question with the project heirarchy

Comment: You can add it in the index.html file as well. However, by having the other pages, your Vue app won't run on all parts of your site, only on those that resolve to index.html. How is your Wordpress set up? Do you set your front-page.php and your blog page in the settings section? All these things play a part in how you'd go about setting this up.

Comment: I only want my vue app to run on the entire site and not the theme. The settings are default haven't touched anything. Apparently in twentytwentythree theme there are not much .php file as you might see in the picture in my question

Comment: http://wordpress2.v3dev.komodefi.com/ 
I have changed index and home but it does not display the default vue page instead it does display the html I added

Comment: have you built the vue app, and have you enqued the relevant assets?

Comment: I have added the enqueue script in my question

Comment: http://wordpress2.v3dev.komodefi.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwentythree/path/to/your/vue-app.js?ver=1.0 is your path. You have to update the path/to/your portion of the path to the actual path.

Comment: Same way I am doing now but like I am doing now but with the url?

Comment: Also is a functions.php required or enqueue script.php works?

Comment: There's different ways to do it, but essentially, you want to require_once your enqueue_script.php file in your functions.php. Your directory is completely open, so I took a look. I did not find the dist folder (where your vue build should presumably be). So you have to build your vue app, add it to the theme directory and then reference the files from your enqueue_script.php file.

Comment: And the functions.php should be in the themes folder as well right? Can you update the answer with functions.php? Please

Comment: Does not work I have updated my question with both enqueue script and functions.php. I setup the project via vite by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254255/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-artistahmed).

Comment: Done, check chat

Comment: Have you got my messages?