# How to properly create wp enqueue and functions script to run vite frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, vite

I am running twenty-twentythreetheme of WordPress at the moment I have created a default vite Vue project inside my themes folder. I have not found much tutorials online that match my use case.

I want to run the vite frontend on my WordPress website. The following is my enqueue script and functions.php

Functions.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Vue Twenty Seventeen Child Theme Functions and Definitions.
 * Requires Twenty Seventeen and only works in WordPress 4.7 or later.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

 // includes for the callbacks.
include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/enqueue-scripts.php' );

/* hooks and filters */

?>
```

enqueue-scripts.php

```
function enqueue_vue_assets() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/example/dist/assets/index-ec461b82.js', array(), '1.0', true );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/example/dist/assets/index-fc5f319f.css', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_vue_assets' );

?>
```

These files are inside my twenty-twentythreetheme folder. The example is my vite project. I have not made any configurations in vite. Do I need to make any? What changes do I need to make in my enqueue script and functions script.

Also the twentytwentythree theme has mostly .html files on its frontend which I have wiped and added div id=app that should come from the app.vue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to compile assets and automatically render the browser via the `hot` file method in any local Wordpress theme build. Here is a working method of doing this using [Chris Page's](https://gist.github.com/chrispage1) custom php class to handle Vite in Wordpress.

Follow steps below to get Vite running properly in Wordpress  theme...

(example below for [`twentytwentythree`](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentythree/) theme but this will work in any wordpress theme)

### Implement PHP into theme

See Vite php class `Vite.lib.php` code below...

[Gist version by Chris Page](https://gist.github.com/chrispage1/06ac44ac3c01ab0454a935d50b8c9282)

```php
<?php

class Vite {

    /**
     * Flag to determine whether hot server is active.
     * Calculated when Vite::initialise() is called.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private static bool $isHot = false;

    /**
     * The URI to the hot server. Calculated when
     * Vite::initialise() is called.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private static string $server;

    /**
     * The path where compiled assets will go.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private static string $buildPath = 'build';

    /**
     * Manifest file contents. Initialised
     * when Vite::initialise() is called.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private static array $manifest = [];

    /**
     * To be run in the header.php file, will check for the presence of a hot file.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $buildPath
     * @param  bool  $output  Whether to output the Vite client.
     *
     * @return string|null
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function init(string $buildPath = null, bool $output = true): string|null
    {

        static::$isHot = file_exists(static::hotFilePath());

        // have we got a build path override?
        if ($buildPath) {
            static::$buildPath = $buildPath;
        }

        // are we running hot?
        if (static::$isHot) {
            static::$server = file_get_contents(static::hotFilePath());
            $client = static::$server . '/@vite/client';

            // if output
            if ($output) {
                printf(/** @lang text */ '<script type="module" src="%s"></script>', $client);
            }

            return $client;
        }

        // we must have a manifest file...
        if (!file_exists($manifestPath = static::buildPath() . '/manifest.json')) {
            throw new Exception('No Vite Manifest exists. Should hot server be running?');
        }

        // store our manifest contents.
        static::$manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($manifestPath), true);

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue the module
     *
     * @param string|null $buildPath
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function enqueue_module(string $buildPath = null): void
    {
        // we only want to continue if we have a client.
        if (!$client = Vite::init($buildPath, false)) {
            return;
        }

        // enqueue our client script
        wp_enqueue_script('vite-client',$client,[],null);

        // update html script type to module wp hack
        Vite::script_type_module('vite-client');

    }

    /**
     * Return URI path to an asset.
     *
     * @param $asset
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function asset($asset): string
    {
        if (static::$isHot) {
            return static::$server . '/' . ltrim($asset, '/');
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($asset, static::$manifest)) {
            throw new Exception('Unknown Vite build asset: ' . $asset);
        }

        return implode('/', [ get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), static::$buildPath, static::$manifest[$asset]['file'] ]);
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to determine hotFilePath.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function hotFilePath(): string
    {
        return implode('/', [static::buildPath(), 'hot']);
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to determine buildPath.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function buildPath(): string
    {
        return implode('/', [get_stylesheet_directory(), static::$buildPath]);
    }

    /**
     * Return URI path to an image.
     *
     * @param $img
     *
     * @return string|null
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function img($img): ?string
    {

        try {

            // set the asset path to the image.
            $asset = 'resources/img/' . ltrim($img, '/');

            // if we're not running hot, return the asset.
            return static::asset($asset);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // handle the exception here or log it if needed.
            // you can also return a default image or null in case of an error.
            return $e->getMessage(); // optionally, you can retrieve the error message

        }

    }

    /**
     * Update html script type to module wp hack.
     *
     * @param $scriptHandle bool|string
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function script_type_module(bool|string $scriptHandle = false): string
    {

        // change the script type to module
        add_filter('script_loader_tag', function ($tag, $handle, $src) use ($scriptHandle) {

            if ($scriptHandle !== $handle) {
                return $tag;
            }

            // return the new script module type tag
            return '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url($src) . '" id="' . $handle . '-js"></script>';

        }, 10, 3);

        // return false
        return false;

    }

}
```

Place this `Vite.lib.php` class file inside a `lib` folder in your local `twentytwentythree` theme directory, then require `Vite.lib.php` in your `functions.php`.

You then want to create a Theme php class `Theme.lib.php` to handle enqueuing your scripts and css to work with Vite...

```php
<?php

class Theme {

    public function __construct()
    {
        
        // enqueue admin styles scripts
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueue_styles_scripts' ], 20);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function enqueue_styles_scripts(): void
    {

        // enqueue the Vite module
        Vite::enqueue_module();

        // register theme-style-css
        $filename = Vite::asset('resources/scss/theme.scss');

        // enqueue theme-style-css into our head
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style', $filename, [], null, 'screen');

        // register theme-script-js
        $filename = Vite::asset('resources/js/theme.js');

        // enqueue theme-script-js into our head (change false to true for footer)
        wp_enqueue_script('theme-script', $filename, [], null, false);

        // update html script type to module wp hack
        Vite::script_type_module('theme-script');

    }

}

new Theme();
```

Then in your `function.php`, require `Theme.lib.php` after `Vite.lib.php` like this...

```php
<?php

// require libs
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/Vite.lib.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/Theme.lib.php');
```

### Install Vite with NPM into theme

Once you've implemented the above php, let's start a fresh `package.json` in your local theme directory.

> When you get Vite running, you can re-add Vue and
> other dependencies later

Here is the basic `package.json` boilerplate to get your project started with Vite in Wordpress...

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "watch": "npm run dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "production": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.3",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

You will notice we are using [`laravel-vite-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-vite-plugin) in our `package.json`, this Laravel Vite plugin makes it super easy to configure the resources and build directory in our `vite.config.js`, and watches for php file changes in your entire theme!

See working `vite.config.js` below for compiling our `theme.css` and `theme.js` resources to the build folder. This `vite.config.js` file also goes in your local theme directory, the same as your `package.json`...

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(() => ({
    base: '',
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'build',
        assetsDir: 'assets'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            publicDirectory: 'build',
            input: [
                'resources/js/theme.js',
                'resources/scss/theme.scss'
            ],
            refresh: [
                '**.php'
            ]
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: /~(.+)/,
                replacement: process.cwd() + '/node_modules/$1'
            },
        ]
    }
}));
```

Before we install NPM and install Vite build, you need to create a `resources` folder in your local theme directory. Then inside the `resources` folder, create these `img, scss, js` directories and then create empty `theme.scss, theme.js` files, structured like this...

[image]

Now we are ready to run NPM install on our `package.json` configuration.

Open terminal in your theme directory and run this command...

```shell
npm install
```

This command install's our dev dependencies and creates our `node_modules` library root vendor files, plus creates a `package-lock.json` file, so our theme directory now looks like this...

[image]

### Initial Vite project build

Now Vite is installed, we are ready to build our Vite project.

> Before we run Vite build, if you visit your site locally you will
> notice you get a fatal error. This is because we have not
> generated a Vite manifest json file yet. The Vite `manifest.json`
> handles linking between our `resources` files and our cache busted
> `build/assets` files.

OK, let's build our resources with Vite so you can start making some magic!

In your local theme directory, run this command first...

```shell
npm run build
```

Command should return this log...

[image]

You only need to initially run `npm run build` once if you are starting a brand new Vite project. This command initially creates your `build` folder, `build/manifest.json` and `build/assets/..` cache busted files.

**Please note you will need to use `npm run build` again every time you want to build production minified build assets and production `manifest.json`.**

Your theme directory will look like this after initially running `npm run build` for the first time...

[image]

> If you visit your local site you will notice the fatal error has
> gone and the production build `theme.css` and `theme.js` will be
> working!

If your local theme is working with no errors, you can inspect the source code and you will see the `theme.css` and `theme.js` are enqueued like this in the html...

```html
<link href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/vite-wordpress/build/assets/theme-716126ae.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style-css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

```html
<script src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/vite-wordpress/build/assets/theme-13161a16.js" type="module" id="theme-script-js"></script>
```

The above enqueued output is exactly how you want this to look on your `staging` and `production` environments. This is the expected output when our Vite local development `hot` file does not exist!

### Start Vite local dev js server

Finally, we are ready to start the epic Vite local js server and `hot` file for super fast dev compiling and automatic browser asset rendering without refreshing the browser!

Provided you've initially built your Vite `build` files, you can now run this command below to start your local Vite js server and `hot` file to watch for any save changes in your theme.

```shell
npm run dev
```

This command should return a log like this, and shows you that the Vite dev local js server is running...

[image]

And you will notice a `hot` file now exists in your `build` directory...

[image]

If you now refresh your local Wordpress site, will notice our enqueued `theme.css` and `theme.js` html has changed to this...

```html
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/scss/theme.scss" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style-css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

```html
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/theme.js" type="module" id="theme-script-js"></script>
```

And you will also notice an additional script loaded in the `<head>` which is our Vite client js module. This script is handling the `hot` file watcher for any changes made to files in your theme.

```html
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client" type="module" id="vite-client-js"></script>
```

So now we are running Vite dev server, you can start adding code to your `theme.css` and `theme.js` resource files.

Every time you hit save on your resource files, Vite will compile your project and changes will automatically run/update in your browser without refreshing! The same will happen if you edit and save PHP.

### Installing NPM packages and dependancies

While your local Vite dev js server is still running, you can install Vue and other packages via a new terminal window without having to stop the current Vite dev js server watcher.

### Production build and deployment

Once you are ready to build for production, make sure you've exited the Vite dev js server and is no longer running...

Then re-run `npm run build` in your theme directory to build cache busted production files in your `build` directory. The sync `build` directory to `staging` or `production` environments.

Make sure `functions.php`, `Vite.lib.php` and `Theme.lib.php` are also deployed to your `staging` or `production` environments for the `build/assets` to work in your theme.

### Using theme images located in `resources/img`

To use images from the theme `build` folder which are images compiled from the `resources/img` directory to the `build/assets` directory.

The `php` usage is...

```php
<img src="<?=Vite::img('example.png')?>" alt="Example" />
```

And the `scss` usage is...

```css
BODY {
  background-image: url(../img/example.png);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant mate I was able to run it by enquueueing the build files of vite and div id app on index.php but this is gold

Comment: @artistAhmed Nice man, did you get Vite local js server and hot file running using `npm run dev` after initial `npm run build`? This Vite dev is a game changer for live rendering development!

Comment: Only build files at the moment I will be trying your method soon on a different example

Comment: Nice! Report back when you do  it's pretty sick

Comment: I will building a plugin soon which is pretty much gonna enqueue a Vue project and upload it as a zip

Comment: This is quite possibly the most useful, well-organized, helpful stackoverflow answer I have encountered in my over a decade of web development. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 1):

For me on `npm run build` images that were included with `<img src="<?=Vite::img('example.png')?>" alt="Example" />` didn't worked. But I found solution: add this to theme.js file: `import.meta.glob([ '../img/**', ]);`