# Code splitting with Vite in php for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vite, code-splitting

I am failing to understand something that should be simple enough.

In Laravel and Inertia (aka. Laravel, Vite, Vue) you have code splitting out of the box, with some minor tweaks.
Now, as Laravel is basically PHP, I tried all sorts of vite configs to make it work for Wordpress themes, but failed miserably.

I definatelly need help on this one. Thank you in advance.

I have read this -> [How to properly create wp enqueue and functions script to run vite frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573766/how-to-properly-create-wp-enqueue-and-functions-script-to-run-vite-frontend)
but this does not solve the code splitting which I would very much like to achieve.